# JSON object with multiple values

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

How do you extract multiple values from a JSON complex object / multidimensional array?

```
{
    "Items": [{
        "node": {
            "titre": "myTitle",
            "representation": {
                "1": "09 Octobre 2012 - 19:30",
                "2": "10 Octobre 2012 - 20:30",
                "3": "11 Octobre 2012 - 19:30"
            },
            "photo": {
                "1": "photo_1.jpg",
                "2": "photo_2.jpg",
                "3": "photo_3.jpg",
                "4": "photo_4.jpg"
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

For now, I'm using:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    $.each(data.Items, function (i, node) {
        var titre = node.node.titre;
        var representation = node.node.representation;
        var photo = node.node.photo;
    }
    });
```

The result for `titre` is good, but for `representation` and `photos`, it renders:`[object Object]`.

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: Looks like javascript with jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because Your photo here is an object ..

To access the values inside it you would need to use the keys 1 , 2 ,3, 4

```
 So var photo = node.node.photo;  // Is an Object 

 var photo1 = node.node.photo["1"] // photo_1.jpg
   var photo2 = node.node.photo["2"] // photo_2.jpg
   var photo3 = node.node.photo["3"] // photo_3.jpg
```

// same logic applies for representation

```
 var representation1 = node.node.representation["1"] // 09 Octobre 2012 - 19:30
   var representation2 = node.node.representation["2"] // 10 Octobre 2012 - 20:30
   var representation3 = node.node.representation["3"] // 11 Octobre 2012 - 19:30
```

To iterate over this you can try this

```
$.each(node.node.photo , function(key , value){

    console.log( value);
});
```

**[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/LPtvE/)**

**EDIT**

```
entry = {
                representation :[ sps.node.representation["1"],sps.node.representation["2"],sps.node.representation["3"] ],
                title: sps.node.titre,
                image: sps.node.image,
                acteurs: sps.node.acteurs,
                acteursuite: sps.node.acteurs_suite,
                lien: sps.node.lien,
                description: sps.node.corps,
                pics: sps.node.photo
            };

for( var i = 0; i< entry.representation.length ; i++){

     alert(entry.representation[i]);
}
```

//
    [FOR FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ueabw/)

Comment: Unfortunately, my case is complicated: http://jsfiddle.net/elektrorl/QQhU7/  

How could I store the values "iterate way" in the "entry" variable, in my example?

Comment: It is already in an object format right.. If you want to still condense it you can store the representation in an array.. Check Edit

Comment: Wow, I didn't know we could condense like this. In fact, it's logical. But I'm trying something without result on the jsfddle, how could I create the loop to generate representation automatically without the keys?

Answer (score 0):

Photo property is not an array. It is an object. The property value should be enclosed withim `[ ]`.